# How to filter grid data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI to create a grid view which loads the data from model in a database as a list. I would like to know how can I be able to filter the data by firm ID.

Here is my code:

```
@model List<FirmsModel>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            dataSource: { pageSize: 20 }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="view">

    <table id="grid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="FirmID">
                    Firm ID
                </th>
                <th data-field="subjectTitle">
                    Subject Title
                </th>
                <th data-sortable="false">
                    Delete
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var i in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@i.firm_id
                    </td>
                    <td>@i.subject_title
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>             
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, filter by id?

Comment: did you try adding `filterable: true,`?

Comment: yeah but it doesnt left me enter stuff#

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            filterable: 
            {
                mode: "row"
            },
            dataSource: { pageSize: 20 }
        });
    });
</script>
```